# Parsing Problem in Android apk file installation

Tags: android, virtualbox

I am using androidlive3.0 OS in my virtual box.
I want to install one apk file in that. 
I have downloaded that apk file and when I click for installation it is giving me error like "There is some problem in parsing"

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your target sdk the level required for Android 3? 
Have you exported the apk as a signed APK? You cannot take the apk that is created during development and install it on a device, you need to export (and preferrably sign) it first.
Rgs
AJ